# Reduce Sum Over Rows of customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sum

Let's assume I have a data like (diff is the desired output) this and I need to build the diff column :

```
customer      mis_date  sal_Ind sal_amnt Exp_Salary_Monthly diff
    10001     2018-01-01   0      4000    8000            8000
    10001     2018-01-02   1      1000    8000            7000
    10001     2018-01-03   0      9000    8000            7000
    10001     2018-01-04   0      500     8000            7000
    10001     2018-01-05   1      1500    8000            5500
```

Explaination:

The customer have a monthly salary but he is transfering it not in one shot. 
I need to see like a balance (diff column) of the amount of salary that stills need to be deposit in order to get the amount of exp_salary field which is the max amount (diff cannot be negative). How Can I know that a transaction is a salary? Sal_Ind is the answer and that's why the diff doesn't changes when sal_ind = 0.

I trying to figure out a nice and good way to build this field. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are SQL Server 2012 or newer (I don't think 2008 would support this). You can use some Windows Functions magic to get a running total of `sal_amnt` where `sal_ind = 1`, then just subtract that from your `exp_salary_monthly`:

```
SELECT mytable.*,
  exp_salary_monthly - SUM(CASE WHEN sal_ind = 1 THEN sal_amnt ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY mis_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as diff1
FROM mytable;
```

---

[SQLFiddle of this in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76c69/5)

Results from your sample data:

```
+----------+------------+---------+----------+--------------------+------+-------+
| customer |  mis_date  | sal_Ind | sal_amnt | Exp_Salary_Monthly | diff | diff1 |
+----------+------------+---------+----------+--------------------+------+-------+
|    10001 | 2018-01-01 | false   |     4000 |               8000 | 8000 |  8000 |
|    10001 | 2018-01-02 | true    |     1000 |               8000 | 7000 |  7000 |
|    10001 | 2018-01-03 | false   |     9000 |               8000 | 7000 |  7000 |
|    10001 | 2018-01-04 | false   |      500 |               8000 | 7000 |  7000 |
|    10001 | 2018-01-05 | true    |     1500 |               8000 | 5500 |  5500 |
+----------+------------+---------+----------+--------------------+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do cumulative sum :

```
select t.*, 
       Exp_Salary_Monthly - sum(case when sal_ind = 1 then sal_amnt else 0 end) over (partition by customer order by mis_date) as diff
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through joining back an aggregated table and doing a conditional sum based on dates. The code below should do what you need.

```
    Create table #Data
            (
            Customer Varchar(50),
            mis_date datetime,
            sal_Ind int,
            sal_amnt float,
            exp_Salary float
                    )

        Insert INTO #Data Values

        ('10001','2018-01-01','0','4000','8000'),
        ('10001','2018-01-02','1','1000','8000'),
        ('10001','2018-01-03','0','9000','8000'),
        ('10001','2018-01-04','0','500','8000'),
        ('10001','2018-01-05','1','1500','8000')




        Select
        D.Customer,D.mis_date,D.sal_Ind,D.exp_Salary
        ,D.exp_Salary - Sum(Case when d2.mis_date <= D.mis_date and D2.sal_Ind = 1 then D2.sal_amnt else 0 end) as DiffCalc
        From #Data D
        inner join #Data D2 on D.Customer = D2.Customer
        group by D.Customer,D.mis_date,D.sal_Ind,D.exp_Salary
```